# Laravel middleware for login with separate admin table?

Tags: php, laravel

How to create Laravel 5 middleware for login with separate admin table without using users table?

Answer (score 3):

You can define an separate VerfiyCsrfToken file for admin, call is as VerifyAdminCsrfToken.

Your **routes/web.php** file looks like this:

```
    Route::group(array('prefix'=>'Api/v1/admin'),function()
    {
    Route::post('login','AdminController@login');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin.csrf','prefix'=>'Api/v1/admin'],function($router){
       Route::get('getAdminDetails','AdminController@getAdminDetails');     
     /*Call Rest all routes after admin login like this and this request 
     goes through the VerifyAdminCsrfToken.php handle request.*/
    });
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php** looks like this

```
     protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'       => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can'        => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin.csrf' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyAdminCsrfToken::class,
    ];
```

Once the login is successful. set the id_admin and csrf token into headers as X-Id-Admin and X-Admin-Csrf-Token respectively.

**VerifyAdminCsrfToken.php**  => to handle after login routes/apis.

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   class VerifyAdminCsrfToken {

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
   $token = \Request::header('X-Admin-Csrf-Token');
   $id_admin = \Request::header('X-Id-Admin');

   $adminObject=new \App\Models\Admin();
   $adminDetails = $adminObject->checkAdminToken($id_admin,$token); // function to identify the admin in admin model based on id_admin and token.

   // echo Session::token() .'==='. $csrfToken; //exit();
   if(!$adminDetails&&count($adminDetails)==0)
   {
      return \Response::json(array('error'=>true,'message'=>'Unauthorized 
      Request'),401);
   }
   else{  
        $userDet                    =   array();
        $userDet['id_admin']        =   $adminDetails->id_admin;
        $userDet['name']            =   $adminDetails->name;

        $request->userDet=$userDet;

        return $next($request);
   }
   }
```

**AdminController.php** contents are as follows:

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   class AdminController extends Controller
   {
    public function login(Request $request){
    $admin_email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');
    $adminObj = new \App\Models\Admin();
    $loginCheck=$adminObj->checkAdminLogin($admin_email,$password);// function to identify the admin in admin model based in admin_email and password.  
    if($loginCheck&&count($loginCheck)>0){
       $token = $loginCheck->token;
       return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully logged 
       in','user_detail'=>$loginCheck,'csrf_token'=>$token],200);
    }else{
    return response()->json(array('message'=>'These credentials did not 
    match our record'),403);
    }
   }
```

//for api call my admin.js file looks like this. its an angular js file. this is just an example to handle api call from client side.

```
  var SITE_URL=localhost/projectfolder/+'index.php/Api/v1/admin/';
  $scope.credentials={admin_email:'####@gmail.com',password:'###'};
  $http({
                method: "POST",
                timeout: 30000,
                url: SITE_URL+'login',
                data: $.param($scope.credentials),//posting data from login form
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).success(function (data,status) {
                if(status==200)
                {
                    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Admin-Csrf-Token']   = data.token; //For all $http request it will apply this header.

                    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Id-Admin']   = data.user_detail.id_admin; //For all $http request will ll apply this header.

   }).error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.actionDisabled=false;
              if(status==401)
              {
                console.log(data.message);//invalid credentials
              }  
   });

   $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: SITE_URL+'getAdminDetails',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} //with this content type newly set headers(X-Id-Admin,X-Admin-Csrf-Token) will be sent and handled the request thorough Laravel newly created middleware.

    }).success(function (response,status) {
           console.log(response);//admin detailed response from server
    });
```

Comment: In AdminController.php, return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully logged 
       in','user_detail'=>$userDet,'csrf_token'=>$token],200);                 what will be the value of $userDet and $token.

Comment: i edited my answer. 'user_details' & 'token' => details will be fetched from checkadminlogin() function  and assigned to logincheck object.

Comment: could you please explain the following code: $token = \Request::header('X-Admin-Csrf-Token');
 $id_admin = \Request::header('X-Id-Admin');

Comment: If I wont use the angularjs, then what will the code?

Comment: if you are writing ajax api calls then the server side response remains same.